# updating an empty dictionary through a function

Tags: python, function, class, dictionary, methods

I am working on a pep project still, and currently at the stage of creating my own class & functions.  I have created a class where I can find any given ingredient inside my bank of recipes (which is a dictionary); now all i want to do is to be able to save the chosen recipe into an empty dictionary.  This will be the users favourite recipes in a dictionary.

I think I understand the logic/theory side behind it but is stuck on the practical.

```
recipe_bank = {"reciepe1":("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
               "reciepe2":["10 blah blah blah", "20", "30", "40", "50"]}
class ChefEasy():
    def __init__(self, save):
        self.save = save

    def favourites(self):
        my_fav = {}
        for r,d in recipe_bank.items():
            x = {r,d}
            if choose == "y":
                my_fav += x
            print(my_fav)

print("Would you like to save your meal")
choose = input()
if choose == "n":
    print("OK! Enjoy your meal!")
elif choose == "y":
    yes = ChefEasy("y)
    print(yes.save("Your meal has been saved!")
```

This was my original code which gives me -TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.

When i studied this code a bit more I thought it would be best to copy {r,d} into an object (x) and then use the my_fav.update(x) method but I am not too sure if this would work..

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks :)

Comment: `yes.save` is a string and equals `"y"`, you assigned it yourself in `yes = ChefEasy("y")`, so the line `yes.save("Your meal has been saved!")` doesn't have any sense.

Comment: What is the exact question? "*Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.*" - is too broad.

Comment: Basically I wanted to know how to create a function that would a recipe into an empty dictionary. The name of the recipe would be the key, and the value would be the ingredients in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add my two cents. Dicts have the update method

```
someDict = dict(someKey = 1, someOtherKey = 2)
empty    = dict()

empty.update(someDict) # {'someKey': 1, 'someOtherKey': 2}
```

However, the keys must be unique otherwise update will overwrite the existing ones. If the keys can be lists you can also you get with a default

```
someDict = dict(someKey = 1, someOtherKey = 2)
empty    = dict()
for key, value in someDict.items():
    empty[key] = empty.get(key, []) + [value]
print(empty) # {'someKey': [1], 'someOtherKey': [2]}
```

This last method will append the value if the key already exists. Which may be preferred over the method above. Similarly it can be used to count the value associated to the key.

Comment: What if you only want one item eg. just ‘someKey = 1’. If we use the update method it will include all items in someDict which I don’t want.

Comment: Thanks please read the last comment I wrote for @ycx solution he gave; would your solution work just as well if the user was asked at the end if he liked the recipe/meal chosen and would like to save it to their favourites?

Comment: This is different from your original question concerning how you update a dictionary. The method I proposed here relates to the original question. This can be adapted for your needs, however that would require you to write that code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few concepts we should address here.

1. We should be passing in `recipe_bank` into the `ChefEasy` object you are creating. After that, we can pull out the favourite recipe from your `recipe_bank` via the `def favourites(self, my_fav)` function.
2. You have to fix your typo in the lines:

   ```
   yes = ChefEasy("y)
   print(yes.save("Your meal has been saved!")
   ```

   It should be:

   ```
   yes = ChefEasy("y")
   print(yes.save("Your meal has been saved!"))
   ```

I will attempt to fix your class for you in the lines below:

```
recipe_bank = {"reciepe1":("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
               "reciepe2":["10 blah blah blah", "20", "30", "40", "50"]}
class ChefEasy():
    def __init__(self, recipe_dict):
        self.recipe_dict = recipe_dict
        self.favorite_dict = {}

    def favourites(self, recipe_list):
        for recipe in recipe_list:
            for key, value in self.recipe_dict.items():
                if recipe == key:
                    print ('Your favourite recipe has been saved')
                    self.favorite_dict[key] = value

    def displayfavdict(self):
        print (self.favorite_dict)
myChefEasy = ChefEasy(recipe_bank)
myChefEasy.favourites(['reciepe1'])

string = input('enter recipe list here, separated by comma: ') #reciepe2
myChefEasy.favourites(string.split(','))

myChefEasy.displayfavdict()
#{'reciepe1': ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'), 'reciepe2': ['10 blah blah blah', '20', '30', '40', '50']}
```

Comment: you have removed the logic of "if user wanted to save" from original code, why?

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try and get back to you

Comment: I tried this and it worked but I don’t think it worked the way I had in mind. I probably just need to tweak it around a little...

Comment: Basically there will in recipe_bank there will be 100’s of different recipes and when the user picks a recipe that they like they will be promoted if they would like to save it into their favourite list of recipes. Doing so they can open the recipes at a later stage / date and choose just the name of the meal (the key) and the ingredients (list of values) would be printed along with the name of recipe (key, value pair).

Comment: The user is promoted to pick out of a list of 3 separate food groups and I then use that to loop through a separate dictionary called food_bank which is almost the same as the recipe_bank but without the step by step process on how to make the meal. The user is prompted if they like the meal, if they don’t another meal is selected for them; if they do like it then they are prompt if they would like to save the recipe. Maybe it’s because I’m still learning or trying to run before I crawl but even though your code is right and works I don’t see how it can be applied to my applicati

Comment: @Sinclair Akoto Has it helped you understand how a class and a dictionary works in python? If so, please mark as correct answer. Thanks